# Precompile asp.net views with ms build

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, msbuild

When I deploy asp.net application through visual studio I know I can just check `Precompile during publish` and uncheck `Allow precompiled site to be updateable`.

And I want to do the same with `msbuild` tool and I am using `/p:MvcBuildViews=true /p:EnableUpdateable=false` but when I go to `IIS` and open views they still have their content which means they are not precompiled, right?

They should have line `This is a marker file generated by the precompilation tool` as they do when publishing from VS. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

> Precompile asp.net views with ms build

You should use the arguments `/p:PrecompileBeforePublish=true` instead of `/p:MvcBuildViews=true`.

`MvcBuildViews` is often mistakenly considered as something that when activated results in precompiled views. Actually. It is just a thing to include views to build process but it doesn’t compile these to project binaries folder.

When we check the checkbox `Precompile during publish` and uncheck the checkbox  `Allow precompiled site to be updateable` on the file publish options, we will get following properties setting in our `FolderProfile.pubxml` file:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PrecompileBeforePublish>True</PrecompileBeforePublish>
    <EnableUpdateable>False</EnableUpdateable>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

So if you want to do the same with msbuild tool, we should use the arguments:

`/p:PrecompileBeforePublish=true;EnableUpdateable=false`

Besides, since those arguments are stored in the `.pubxml` file(under the PublishProfiles in the Properties node in Solution Explorer). They are now designed to be checked in and shared with team members. These files are now MSBuild files and you can customize them if you wish. In order to publish from the command line just pass `DeployOnBuild=true` and set PublishProfile to the name of the profile:

```
msbuild.exe "TestPrecompiled.csproj" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile.pubxml
```

Of course, you can use the arguments and the `.pubxml` file at the same time, the arguments in the command line will overwrite the property in the `.pubxml` file:

```
msbuild.exe "TestPrecompiled.csproj" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile.pubxml /p:PrecompileBeforePublish=true;EnableUpdateable=false
```

After publish completed, open the .cshtml file in the publish folder, we will get the line `This is a marker file generated by the precompilation tool, and should not be deleted!` as they do when publishing from VS:

[image]

[image]

See [Precompiling ASP.NET WebForms and MVC Views with MSBuild](https://help.veracode.com/reader/4EKhlLSMHm5jC8P8j3XccQ/eP7B7mh55YlLmKLo~mWEgA) for some more details.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was really helpfull :)