# Updatable razor view within precompiled website

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on a project where website has couple of views (*.cshtml) files that must be kept updatable and must not be precompiled. In order to achieve better performance rest of the website views must be precompiled.

The issue that I am facing is that I am getting following error whenever updatable view is requested

> The file 'abc.cshtml' has not been pre-compiled, and cannot be
>   requested.

I am trying to find a solution since last couple of days but no luck so far. I would really appreciate if someone could point me into right direction.

Comment: What have you done to make this view updateable, while the rest of the site is not?

Comment: Excluded it from build and copied it over using MSBUILD copy task.

Comment: Have you tried precompiling using msbuild?
As in this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49028212/precompile-asp-net-views-with-ms-build

Comment: I am using same settings through pubxml file. If I choose to set updatable true it won't precompile any of my views.

Comment: @JonP Any idea?

Comment: I actually doubt you can achieve this seeing the option is "precompile **site**". If this was an option I thought it would be configurable via pubxml, and I've been unable to find anything that looks remotely like what you want.